# Getting a web socket connection error when I haven't attempted to connect to anything (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, signalr

I am adding signalR to my react project. I've installed @microsoft/signalr which seems to be working fine (after a bit of updating other packages). The issue I'm having is, before I even tried to connect to a back end the browser console is showing the following error

```
WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:65043/ws' failed: 
WebSocketClient @ WebSocketClient.js:16
initSocket @ socket.js:21
(anonymous) @ socket.js:45
```

I have no idea where the attempt to connect is being initiated. I'm not sure if it's even an issue but I am very new to signalR and web sockets in general so I'd just like a bit of clarification.